# Disable back button for previous activities, but exit with double pressed

Tags: android, back

Is there any way to disable in an activity the back button (to prevent show the previous activities), but also when you double press it, use it for exit??
I use this code that I found, but it only makes the second part. Close the app with double press..
What I try to do, is also prevent to go back and show the last visited activities. Thank you.

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press again back for exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

UPDATE

I make the changes that you suggest, but now, it shows with the double back all the previous visited activities.

```
static final long THRESHOLD = 2000;
long backLastPressed;

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - backLastPressed < THRESHOLD) {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again back for exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
        backLastPressed = 0;
        return;
    }
    backLastPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Otherwise, ignore this BACK press
}
```

Comment: This code looks right. So what happens when you press back button once?

Comment: It starts to show all the previous activities I been to, poping all the time the Toast msg, until the start and then I double press and exit.

Comment: Could you post more code? I suppose there is problem outside of this scope

Comment: I use it on the basic template of Android studio to test it, with only one intent with no further code...
I thought it would be easy to modify the code I posted, but I couldn't make it.. I just want one tap, do nothing, two taps, exit..

Answer (score 0):

You could store an internal variable that marks the time of when the BACK button was pressed. Every time in `onBackPressed` check if the time now is within your double-tap threshold and if so, register it as a double-tap.

Try something like this:

```
static final long THRESHOLD = 2000;
long backLastPressed = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - backLastPressed < THRESHOLD) {
        // TODO: Register double-tapped BACK button, put your "exit" code here
        backLastPressed = 0;
        return;
    }
    backLastPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Otherwise, ignore this BACK press
}
```

Don't call `super.onBackPressed()` if you're trying to override the BACK button behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I try it and it never ends the app.. Regardless of how many times I press the back button, it doesn't end the app..

Comment: Well, what do you mean never end the app? You need to replace where I commented `Register double-tapped BACK button` with whatever code you want to run after the double-tap is detected. In your case, I don't know the specifics of how you want to "exit" you app, perhaps calling "finish()"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it.. Although, I put my code where you said and still shows all the previous activities I had visit when I double press the back button..I will edit my post to show you how I modify it..

Comment: I see, if that's the case then what you're really looking for is how to close out your Application along with all other activities. I suggest you do a quick search on SO on ways to do that. Apologies if my answer wasn't immediately helpful.

Comment: I have made a quick research and I found how to terminate the application, without go to the previously visited activities, with only this @Override
public void onBackPressed() {} but I want something where, disable the back button and delete the previous visited activities, but with double pressed the back button, exit the app.. Could you help me with that? Thank you again!

Comment: I'm sorry but your phrasing is sort of confusing, specifically are you trying to  just exit the app after double tapping the BACK button?

Comment: One tap back button, do nothing(not show the previous activities). Two tap back button exit.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have the reputation to comment.

To prevent visiting the previous activities, you could, in addition to the code to do something when you double-tap back button, clear the tasks when you enter in this activity.

This guide shows how to achive this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

TL;DR: use flags in the intent to clear the activity back stack.

In the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the previous activity
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but it stuck in a loop where it goes all the time to the same activity with never ends the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code :

```
private static long back_press;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (back_press + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();      

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please press again to exit!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_press = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

It worked for me, i hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but the same problem.. What I need is 1 tap, nothing(not show the previous activities), 2 taps exit..

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at this sample app: https://github.com/IvanShafran/android-stackoverflow/tree/master/BackButtonHandle

Main point is:

```
private boolean mIsBackButtonPressedBefore = false

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mIsBackButtonPressedBefore) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Second back button press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mIsBackButtonPressedBefore = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "First back button press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It has described behaviour as you can see at the gif below:[image]

If your code is similar to this but doesn't work you should look for a problem outside of this scope.